# Perfectly forward a lambda and store it as a function object in C++14/17

Tags: lambda, c++14

How can we perfectly forward a lambda and store it to a given function object with fixed signature? The lambda is actually defined by users and can return either an integer or nothing, with arbitrary numbers of arguments. If the given lambda has no return, the wrapper should return a default value (say -1), or simply return whatever it is from the lambda.

```
std::function<int()> func;

auto L1 = [](char joe) {
  return 1;
}

auto L2 = [](char joe, float num) {
  // no return
}
```

Using the above example, I believe variadic template can help.

```
template <
  typename C, typename... T, typename R = std::result_of_t<C(T...)>,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<void, R> *= nullptr >
>
auto make_function(C&& c, T&&... args) {
  return [&]() { c(args...); return -1; }
}

template <
  typename C, typename... T, typename R = std::result_of_t<C(T...)>,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, R> *= nullptr >
>
auto make_function(C&& c, T&&... args) {
  return [&]() { return c(args...); }
}
```

And I may need something like this:

```
func = make_function(L1, 'a');
func = make_function(L2, 'b', 1.2f);
```

I don't know whether implementing such thing is feasible. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the lambda need to be called multiple times with different values for its arguments?

Comment: yes...this is what makes me no idea

Comment: I don't understand what functionality is missing from your snippet... Do you want `L1` to be copied/moved into the resulting function object, instead of just captured by reference?